# Getting a page to reload where it was when back or forward button was clicked

Tags: javascript, html

I have [this page](https://wayneca.neocities.org/WebDesign/TagList.html) that has two tables. The left table is a list of links that point to items in the right table using A href='#itemid' with the corresponding A id='itemid' in the right table. It works fine when you're just clicking links in the left table, but if I click the back or forward button the page reloads but doesn't return to the position it was in. The page URL includes the #itemid, so I don't understand why the page doesn't return to that position when the back or forward button is clicked. Also, the first load is just the webpage name without a hashtag, so I also need to know how to tell the browser to reload the page with both tables at the top. Currently, the only way I can get it to cooperate is by holding SHIFT and clicking the refresh button.

I have tried every refresh example I can find and none of them work.

```
META http-equiv='refresh' content='0'
```

This was disastrous, just kept constantly refreshing the page.

```
window.location,refresh();
document.location.refresh();
location.refresh();
```

All of those in a unLoad() attribute in the BODY tag, with and without true as the argument to the refresh function. I really don't want my web host's server constantly having to serve the page anyway, so true isn't an option even if it did work.

I am out of ideas. I also understand that the history is a single doubly-linked list and the forward and back buttons just move through the list in each direction, but you would think the action would result in the page being reloaded the way it looked the last time you were on that page, not like you're still on the page you were last on.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the [history API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API), to push and pop states according to your needs.

Every time you click one of your links, you need to push a state and a location so that when you press the back button, that state is restored with the given location.

Below is an example on how you might use it. I would not recommend managing the whole page content with innerHTML. This is just done for simplicity. What you are doing in the callback and with the state, and under what circumstances you use saveState to push extra state, is up to you.

```
const router = (hook = console.log) => {
  window.onpopstate = ({ state }) => hook(new URL(window.location.href), state);
  hook(new URL(window.location.href));
  return {
    anchorHandler: e => {
      e.preventDefault();
      window.history.pushState(null, "", e.target.href);
      hook(new URL(e.target.href));
      return false;
    },
    saveState: (state, href = window.location.href) => {
      window.history.pushState(state, "", href);
    }
  };
};

const locations = {
  "/": (state) => `<h1>Home</h1>
    <p>Type something in this input. If you blur it, it will be saved as state.
      Now you can navigate back and forth to remove/restore it. <br />
      For example, type something and navigate to the about page. Then press the back button.
      </p>
      <br />
    <input
      value="${state?.text || ''}"
      onblur="saveState({text: this.value})"
    />
  `,
  "/about": (state) => `<h1>About</h1>`,
  "/contact": (state) => `<h1>Contact</h1>`,
}

pageContent = document.getElementById("page-content");

const { saveState, anchorHandler } = router((location, state) =>
  pageContent.innerHTML = locations[location.pathname]
    ? locations[location.pathname](state)
    : locations["/"](state)
);

document
  .querySelectorAll("a")
  .forEach(a => a.addEventListener("click", anchorHandler));
```

```
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="/about">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="/contact">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
<main>
  <div id="page-content"></div>
</main>
```

I cannot show it as snippet because, SO, as security limitations around the usage of the history API. You can check pull this repo and run it locally https://github.com/bluebrown/spa-router-example, or visit this page where I have deployed that repo, https://spa-router-example.pages.dev/.

Comment: I have no doubt that this is the answer, but I am unable to wrap my head around it without a proper example of using it. I have tried about 5 ways of doing it and none of them are even close to correct. The example code they show is not enough to invoke the response I'm looking for. I could use a working example.

Comment: @WayneCa, see my updated answer. Note that this is just one way of doing it and might not be the best or particularly suited for your situation. It is just there to give you an idea.

Comment: Thanks for this example. It is deeper into JavaScript than I have ever gone. My experience with JavaScript was in the 90s and it was vastly different than it is now. I will be studying this code and I will see if I can get it to work for me, but I will likely have more questions before it works. Thanks again for the help. I will flag this as the answer.

Comment: @WayneCa, I might have confused you though. I just noticed that you are asking about links with a `#` aka named anchors.  those work differently.  I am not sure if a history router is required for those. I will double-check this.

Comment: @WayneCa, if you look here, the named anchors work with history. https://www.tagindex.net/html/link/anchor_example1s.html Maybe you have a different problem.

Comment: Thanks. I am studying what you provided for clues, but if it turns out it must be done differently with hashtags then I will be interested in seeing what's different. That helps me grok more than just one example does.

Comment: @WayneCa IMO, hashtags should just work out of the box. No fancy js required.

Comment: Maybe it's because I'm using two tables inside an outer table then. The example you just showed me is the behavior I was expecting and didn't get. The reason for the outer table is to get the other tables to align side-by-side and be centered in the viewport. I will provide a small example of what I am doing so you can see the layout.

Comment: @WayneCa, maybe you are right. It could be because you have tables in a table cell. Have you tried to solve your alignment with flexbox or css grid instead and use a single table?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/WayneCa/dky164gv/2/ is an example of my layout. The css it uses is necessary to get the look I am getting. Take any part out or change it and the whole thing breaks layout-wise. I am not familiar with flexbox or css grid.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241982/discussion-between-the-fool-and-wayneca).